# How to create a drop-up menu in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jpopup

I've tried searching for quite some time now, but I guess either I'm unable to find the exact keyword or there is no solution available.

I want to create a menu in the footer of my JFrame, such that on clicking, it drops-up unlike normal menus that drops-down

On what exactly I mean by drop-up, please see a similar menu in css -http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_pullup.html

Comment: please consider adding comment while voting down, so that I can improve

Comment: Check this example [here][1], its very helpful


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475417/make-jpopupmenu-display-with-a-certain-bottom-left-coordinate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is using buttons with JPopupMenu. The menu location can be specified when showing the menu:

```
menu.show(parentComponent, 0, -menu.getPreferredSize().height);
```

would place the menu above `parentComponent` like in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for others who stumble upon this question :

```
JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();

        JMenuItem mnuNew = new JMenuItem("New");
        popupMenu.add(mnuNew);
        JMenuItem mnuOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
        popupMenu.add(mnuOpen);
        JMenuItem mnuClose = new JMenuItem("Close");
        popupMenu.add(mnuClose);

        JButton btnMenu = new JButton("Popup");
        btnMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                popupMenu.show(btnMenu, 0, -popupMenu.getPreferredSize().height);
            }
        });
```